# Database for sovereign bond upgrades/downgrades

Tags: data-request, finance

I am looking for a database of sovereign bond upgrades/downgrades by Moodys/Fitch/Standard & Poors, for as many countries as possible.

I would need:

date|country|rating before|rating after|outlook